# Plot undetermined number of plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pca

I am trying to plot the contents of a Principal Component Analysis using *ggplot2*. I would like to generate a single pdf with all plots in it with a user-specified number of principal components to show (so if user says 3, it would plot PC 1 vs 2, 1 vs 3 and 2 vs 3).

I've looked into *gridextra* and but not entirely sure how to add multiple plots when I don't know exactly how many components will be selected.

Comment: Finally, somebody on SO who plots **more than two principal components**! I had a different question (about putting multiple PCA plots in a grid) and nobody on SO cares about plotting more than two dimensions of their PCA :D Anyway, the `cowplot` package seems to do exactly what I want, so thanks for your question, as the answer brought that package to my attention ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start, get user input (*input_nPC*), get combination then loop through and plot subset of data:

```
library(ggplot2)

# example data
myPC <- data.frame(
  pc1 = runif(10),
  pc2 = runif(10),
  pc3 = runif(10),
  pc4 = runif(10))

# user input, e.g.: 3 out of 4 PCs
input_nPC <- 3

# check: must be at least 2 PCs
input_nPC <- max(c(2, input_nPC))

# get combination
combo <- combn(input_nPC, 2)

pdf("myOutput.pdf")

for(i in seq(ncol(combo))){
  d <- myPC[, combo[, i]]
  d_cols <- colnames(d)
  gg <- ggplot(d, aes_string(x = d_cols[1], y = d_cols[2])) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(paste(d_cols, collapse = " vs "))
  print(gg)
}

dev.off()
```

---

If we need to have output as one page PDF, then using *cowplot* package:

```
ggList <-
  apply(combo, 2, function(i){

    d <- myPC[, i]
    d_cols <- colnames(d)
    ggplot(d, aes_string(x = d_cols[1], y = d_cols[2])) +
      geom_point() +
      ggtitle(paste(d_cols, collapse = " vs "))

  })

pdf("myOutput.pdf")
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = ggList)
dev.off()
```

---

Or we can use `GGally::ggpairs` as below:

```
library(GGally)

ggpairs(myPC[, 1:input_nPC])
```

Comment: Ahhhh, yeah, that is what I was wondering, cowplot can actually read lists of ggplot objects, that is fantastic to know, thank you!